# Webcam image that displayed by pressing a button

Tags: javascript, image, webcam, display

I am coding a website. My webcam sends images to my server and I want my website displaying one of them by pressing a button.

Here is my code. It works but it needs to be simpler like with a switch system.

```html
<img id="img0" src="wetter/webcam/blickliftcam0.jpg">
<div id="imgwetter">
    <img id="img7" src="wetter/webcam/blickliftcam7.jpg">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i0 = document.getElementById("img0");
    var i7 = document.getElementById("img7");
    var i8 = document.getElementById("img8");
    var i9 = document.getElementById("img9");
    var i10 = document.getElementById("img10");
    var i11 = document.getElementById("img11");
    var i12 = document.getElementById("img12");
    var i13 = document.getElementById("img13");
    var i14 = document.getElementById("img14");
    var i15 = document.getElementById("img15");
    var i16 = document.getElementById("img16");

    function img0() {
        i0.style.display = "block";
        i7.style.display = "none";
        i8.style.display = "none";
        i9.style.display = "none";
        i10.style.display = "none";
        i11.style.display = "none";
        i12.style.display = "none";
        i13.style.display = "none";
        i14.style.display = "none";
        i15.style.display = "none";
        i16.style.display = "none";
    }

    function img7() {
        i0.style.display = "none";
        i7.style.display = "block";
        i8.style.display = "none";
        i9.style.display = "none";
        i10.style.display = "none";
        i11.style.display = "none";
        i12.style.display = "none";
        i13.style.display = "none";
        i14.style.display = "none";
        i15.style.display = "none";
        i16.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>

<input class="akbutton" type="button" value="Aktuelles Bild" OnClick="img0()">
<div id="buttonleiste">
    <input class="cbutt" type="button" value="7 Uhr" onclick="img7()">
</div>
```

Comment: You can simply change the image url on button click. `i0.setAttribute('src', 'wetter/webcam/blickliftcam' + hour + '.jpg')`. You only need one `img` function with the parameter `hour` and use it like that: `onclick="img(1)"`

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function setImage (hour) {
      document.getElementById('current-image').setAttribute('src', 'wetter/webcam/blickliftcam' + hour + '.jpg')
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <img id="current-image" src="wetter/webcam/blickliftcam12.jpg">
  <div class="buttonleiste">
    <!-- buttons for 01:00 - 06:00 -->
    <input class="cbutt" type="button" value="7 Uhr" onclick="setImage(7)">
    <input class="cbutt" type="button" value="8 Uhr" onclick="setImage(8)">
    <!-- buttons for 09:00 - 24:00 -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```